# How can I ignore parent widget's tooltip in child widget in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, tooltip, qwidget

I have a QWidget that a tooltip has been set on using setTooltip and within that widget, I have a child widget.

The problem is that the child widget doesn't have a tooltip specified (i.e. "") but the tooltip of the parent widget is shown. If I do specify a non-blank tooltip in the child widget then it is shown instead of the parent widget's tooltip.

How do I supress this behaviour and have no tooltip shown in the child?

Thanks,
Alan

Comment: Install an event filter to the parent widget and suppress the tool tip event?

Comment: Thanks for your help, I got it working using Hank's sample below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As vahancho said, an event filter should do what you want:

```
Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{
    setToolTip("This is a parent tooltip");

    child = new QWidget(this);
    child->installEventFilter(this);
}

bool Widget::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
{
    if (obj == child && event->type() == QEvent::ToolTip)
    {
        QToolTip::hideText();// this hides the parent's tooltip if it is shown
        return true;// this filters the tooltip event out of processing
    }

    return QWidget::eventFilter(obj, event);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this does what I want.